# support new Indian currency symbol in java

Tags: java, numbers, currency

how to format a number with new Indian currency symbol(₹) using java.if there is any workaround let us share .

Answer (score 4):

Until Java properly supports the new character you can manually specify the currency symbol using its unicode value.

The Unicode for the Indian currency symbol is `U+20B9`

So to insert this character into a java string you specify it as `\u20B9` instead of the default DecimalFormat currency value of `\u00A4`

For example:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 000");
```

Unfortunately this will hard code your output to always display the rupee symbol.  If you need to support multiple locales you can check the user.country system property.

```
boolean iAmInIndia = "IN".equals(System.getProperty("user.country"));
DecimalFormat formatter = iAmInIndia ? new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 000") : new DecimalFormat("\u00A4 000");
```

Also, the component you are using to display this string must have a font which contains the currency symbol.  Arial on Window 7 does, however many others don't.

Comment: A better alternative than the pattern would be to use currencyInstance of NumberFormat and update the currency symbol on its internal DecimalFormatSymbols metadata.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.karnataka.gov.in/Documents/Rupee_Foradian.ttf copy this font in windows fonts folder(in RUN ->type fonts).

then 
  Font ProMed_Font=new Font("Rupee Foradian",Font.PLAIN,10);
set above font to label

example:label.settext("100"+"`")  output will be 100+rupee symblol

[image: PLease enter the key properly as showed in image]